# Error showing missing return statement even returning

Tags: java, android, android-browser

how to do it? Here I want to get the data. the result in html page. I want to show it in my app to the end user. Will the html document automatically present the page. Or will it be the same html code on the display. I used this source
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask to make this app.  the modification is I want to show the complete page.

```
public char readIt(InputStream stream)throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
       Reader reader = null;
       reader = new InputStreamReader(stream,"UTF-8");
       int k = reader.read();
       while (k != -1) {
           return (char) reader.read();
           k = reader.read();
       }
   }
```

Comment: if k == -1 before entering while loop, you are not returning anything

Comment: You while loop is not guaranteed to run

Comment: What your code should `if k==-1` ? It should return outside the loop. You can return earlier depending on your while loop iteration.

Comment: You need to ensure that your method will return your value under all circumstances. In other words, what will happen if it wont come into while loop?

Comment: If you want to show the complete page, why does your method's return type is set to `char` ?

Comment: If I have to return at the end of while loop, how will I collect all the data into a variable. Page content should be carried by the reader. I thought I can only do that in a loop returning each character seperately.

Comment: @Titus. I'm new to programming. I thought there will be both images and strings in a web page. I have to read them individually and should present them on the page. I displayed the data using output.setText() in text view. If I have to display a web page, how can I do that?

Comment: You should take a look at [WebView](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) this is an Android `View` that can be used to display web pages. The entire source code of a web page is a `String`. The images in a web page are usually represented by HTML `<img>` elements and are downloaded separately from the page's source code.

Answer (score 1):

If your code does not get into while loop what will it return? The return statement should be there in any case as specified by method signature. Also your while loop looks problematic to me as you have first statement itself as return statement.

The method should have following kind of structure:

```
public char readIt(InputStream stream)throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
       Reader reader = null;
      // do processing
      return reader;
}
```